# Special Character Pattern Matching in Python

Tags: python, regex, string

I have to match this pattern [**] inside a given string but its not giving accurate result.

```
import re
str1 = '[**] [1:123:43] hello madam [**]'
m1 = re.match('/[/*/*/] .*', str1)
```

Please Help!!

Comment: You scape with the backslash symbol (`\\`)

Comment: You should also look at using RegexBuddy, it's extremely helpful when building regex statements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use backslash(`\`) to escape meta characters, not forward-slash (`/`):

```
>>> import re
>>> str1 = '[**] [1:123:43] hello madam [**]'
>>> m1 = re.match(r'\[\*\*\] .*', str1)
>>> m1
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x0000000002898100>
>>> m1.group()
'[**] [1:123:43] hello madam [**]'
```

BTW, using `r'raw string literal'`, you don't need to escape backslash itself.

---

If you just want to check that the string start with `[**]`, use [`str.startswith`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.startswith):

```
>>> str1.startswith('[**]')
True
```